# How to suppress default event of link made by JsHelper for Ajax request? (cakePHP)

Tags: jquery, ajax, hyperlink, cakephp-2.0

**Goal:** I want to click a link and have the html returned by the resulting ajax call loaded into a div.

I've made a link using the JsHelper like so:

```
<?php echo $this->Js->link('Do some ajax!', array( 
            'controller' => 'items',
            'action' => 'view',
            1
        ), array('update' => '#item'));?>
```

but instead of following through on the ajax request, the link is followed.

In jQuery the default event of the link could be repressed using `event.preventDefault()` but I can find no obvious way to tell the JsHelper to do this.

**Question:** How can I prevent the default event of the link? *Alternatively*; should I really not be using a link at all? If so, what should I be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason the link was followed was really stupid. I hadn't included jQuery properly... There is no way to save face here. :/ Many thanks to Jared for trying to help me though!

Comment: Can't, it says something on the lines of "This question have answers and can't be deleted. Flag it for moderator attention instead.".

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [JsHelper docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#JsHelper%3a%3aevent), it looks like you would put them side-by-side:

```
echo $this->Js->link(
    'Do some ajax!', 
     array('controller' => 'items','action' => 'view', 1), 
     array('update' => '#item')
);
this->Js->event('click', $this->Js->alert('hey you!'));
```

I doubt you want the `alert()` in there, but that's from the docs and I don't have anything else. it appears to default to `return false;`, which is what you should be using to cancel a click. This is what it actually outputs in the markup:

```
$('#some-link').bind('click', function (event) {
    alert('hey you!');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Using this doesn't do anything but produces code for both an ajax request *and* an alert. Neither of which is run since the link is followed.

`$(document).ready(function () {$("#link-1220818477").bind("click", function (event) {$.ajax({dataType:"html", success:function (data, textStatus) {$("#item").html(data);}, url:"\/items\/view\/1"});
return false;});
$("#link-1220818477").bind("click", function (event) {alert("hey you!");
return false;});});`

Comment: You mean outputs it to the page? Sure. Were you looking for something else?

Comment: The question is: *How can I prevent the default event of the link?*. Or perhaps I'm missinterpreting your answer?

Comment: You can't, with `$this-Js->link()`, and if you could, it would do the same thing. Write Javascript out.

Comment: Alright, so you're saying I should try to do this some other way without `$this->Js->link()`. How would you do it?

Comment: I'm not saying that. I'm not a "no JS/CSS in the body tag!!" kinda guy. But I would probably put it in an include and use selectors or something. It's up to you, though. You could put it all in the `head`. Depends on how it's best organized. I don't know anything about JsHelper, I just know what's it's up to because they're all more or less the same.